# Hola, tengo que hacer un grid generalizado con un wuc y establecer el tipo de columnas

Tags: checkbox, datagridview, gridview

Ya se establecio las columnas para dos tipos, de texto y link, solo falta checkbox, si pudieran ayudarme a encontrar una solucion porque no se me ocurre :(

```
Public Sub EstablecerColumnas(listaColumnas As List(Of Entidad.ColumnaGridView), dataKeys() As String)
        GridView1.Columns.Clear()
        GridView1.DataKeyNames = dataKeys

        For Each columna In listaColumnas
            If columna.TipoColumna Is Nothing OrElse columna.TipoColumna = "Texto" Then
                Dim columnaTexto = New BoundField
                columnaTexto.HeaderText = columna.Titulo
                columnaTexto.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = columna.AlineacionTitulo
                columnaTexto.DataField = columna.CampoDatos
                columnaTexto.SortExpression = columna.CampoOrdenar
                columnaTexto.ReadOnly = True
                If columna.Formato <> String.Empty Then
                    columnaTexto.DataFormatString = columna.Formato
                End If
                If columna.Alineacion <> Nothing Then
                    columnaTexto.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = columna.Alineacion
                End If
                GridView1.Columns.Add(columnaTexto)
            ElseIf columna.TipoColumna = "Link" Then
                Dim ColumnaLink = New ButtonField
                ColumnaLink.HeaderText = columna.Titulo
                ColumnaLink.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = columna.AlineacionTitulo
                ColumnaLink.Text = columna.TextoLink
                ColumnaLink.CommandName = columna.Comando
                ColumnaLink.ButtonType = ButtonType.Link
                If columna.Alineacion <> Nothing Then
                    ColumnaLink.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = columna.Alineacion
                End If
                GridView1.Columns.Add(ColumnaLink)

            ElseIf columna.TipoColumna = "Checkbox" Then

            End If
        Next
```